# Why when deleting a file named ^V^V in Zsh it deletes all visible files with it?

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, command-line-interface, zsh

I was trying to delete a file named ^V^V (created by fooling around in Vim), but failed because I didn't know how to escape the carets. So I copied and pasted it instead and used the trash command (cli utility for MacOS) and it deleted all visible files with it. I noticed because the Alacritty terminal was warning me the config file was gone.

This is the command I typed:

```
trash ^V^V
```

**^V^V meaning caret and uppercase v, not Ctrl V.**

Here you can get the Cli utility (recommended if you use MacOS):
https://github.ink/sindresorhus/macos-trash

The result was it sent to the trash all files in the current directory.

Comment: Did you create a file named `^V^V` or `$'\026\026'`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with `rm`. What was the exact command you called? FWIW, one would usually quote files with strange names or use double hyphens as in `rm -- ^V^V`. The caret might have a special meaning in your MacOS CLI utility.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am using this cli tool (if you are using MacOS I recommend it): https://github.com/sindresorhus/macos-trash

Comment: @MiguelCortes because `^V` (caret V) and `^V` (Ctrl+V) are completely different, although visibly they look the same

Comment: @phuclv I am learning that, but you are not really answering the question, how are they different? Why are all visible files getting deleted?

Comment: I never said I'm answering the question. I show the reason why choroba asked that. Because no one knows what keys you actually entered. `^V^V` literally is `5E 56 5E 56` in binary, while Ctrl+V is `\026\026` or `0x22 0x22` in binary, and will display on the screen as `^V`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, asking technical questions is difficult.

Comment: @phuclv Yesterday I created a file named \026\026 created by pressing Ctrl V four times, but it was not being displayed as ^V^V but as ??. I had to use rm space and then tab to be able to select '\026\026' and delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the man page `zshexpn`, in the context of filename generation, `^` takes on a special meaning, if extended globbing is set:

> ^x
>
> (Requires EXTENDED_GLOB to be set.) Matches anything except the pattern x. This has a higher precedence than '/', so '^foo/bar' will search directories in '.' except './foo' for a file named 'bar'.

Assuming you have extended glob set, `^V^V` (that is the four byte sequence, not two times the escape-code) expands to everything not starting with an upper case 'V'. Example session:

```bash
╓╴                                                                                               z[10:21]╶╖
╙╴~/scratch/zsh❯ ls                                                                         07:31 17:40 ╜
 B_file.txt   F_file.txt   V_file.txt
╓╴                                                                                               z[10:21]╶╖
╙╴~/scratch/zsh❯ ls ^V^V                                                                    07:31 17:40╜
 B_file.txt   F_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to answer the question. I don't remember setting EXTENDED_GLOB, but I have installed a framework that comes with some plugins to get Fish shell like interactivity and such. So that could explain it.

Comment: You can check with `setopt | grep glob` - see if `extendedglob` is in the set options.

Comment: It seems it is, I got this when executing setopt | grep glob:
nocaseglob
extendedglob

Answer (score 0):

First things first: Vim is Vim, not Vi. They have lots of things in common but even more differences. If you absolutely want to learn from a book, pick [a book about Vim](https://pragprog.com/titles/dnvim2/practical-vim-second-edition/), not [a book about Vi](https://www.ele.uri.edu/faculty/vetter/Other-stuff/vi/vi-intro.pdf).

Your problem, beside using the wrong book, is that you don't read it carefully. `^V` is not the `^` character followed by the `V` character, it is the literal representation of `CTRL+V`. In the given example, you are told to…

1. enter the command-line with `:`:

   ```
   :
   ```
2. insert `map q :wq`:

   ```
   :map q :wq
   ```
3. press `^V` (`CTRL+V`) two times (maybe a Vi thing, you only need to do it once in Vim),
4. press `Carriage Return` once so that its literal value (`^M`) is inserted:

   ```
   :map q :wq^M
   ```
5. press `Carriage Return` one more time to execute the command you just typed.

The actual mapping is:

```
map q :wq^M
```

where `^M` is a literal `CTRL+M` character, not:

```
map q :wq^V^VCR CR
```

where `^` is `^`, `V` is `V`, etc. It is no wonder that your mapping is doing all sorts of crazy things as it is pure gibberish.

As for why the file created by your broken mapping is behaving the way it does? If you do something like:

```
$ rm '^V^VCR CR'
```

or:

```
$ rm \^V\^VCR\ CR
```

then the file is deleted as expected but it is not clear from your messy question what you *actually do*.

A few suggestions:

- Use a Vim book to learn how to use Vim.
- Your computer already comes with a terminal emulator, use it. You are not comfortable enough with all this to fully understand the pros and cons of installing an alternative.
- Just use the built-in `ZZ` next time.

Comment: In case you missed it, the events leading up to OP's question were discussed in [a question on Vi and Vim SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/44154/how-to-map-q-for-saving-and-quitting). You generally confirm their points.

Comment: Hmm… I will copy my answer over there, then.

Comment: It's a different question... but your answer applies more to the original question than to this one ... which seems to be about bash and the elusive macos cli trash utility... as far as I can tell.

Comment: I will stay with Alacritty, thank you very much. It has not posed any problems so far and it's far faster than the default Mac terminal.

BTW, I am already reading the Vim book, I am just starting chapter 4. :)

Comment: In both bash and zsh, `^` can introduce history substitutions in some contexts. For instance, in zsh, `^V^VCR` will rerun the last command, but with with "V" replaced by "VCR". This may (or may not) be part of the reason for what happened, but in any case it's good practice to quote any shell arguments that contain `^`.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting because I am using the standard MacOS shell, in other words, Zsh. I will update my initial post.

Comment: @MiguelCortes If you want someone to figure out what happened, you'll have to give the *exact* sequence of commands you entered (and since there's a possible history substitution involved, that includes the command *before* any that had "^" in them). You also be very clear about whether you typed "^" followed by "V", or held the Control key and pressed "v" -- "^V" is sometimes used as a visible representation of the normally-invisible character Control-V, but they're totally different things.